# Getting OutOfMemoryError while calling Java High-Level REST Client API

Tags: elasticsearch, resthighlevelclient

My requirements would be I need fetch the data from ElasticsticSearch DB through Java Rest client API using spring boot. So I have written spring boot code as below.

**Dependency in pom.xml:**

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
            <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client</artifactId>
            <version>6.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
            <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
            <version>6.7.0</version>
        </dependency>

and Client class as below:
    private RestHighLevelClient buildClient() {
        if (restHighLevelClient == null) {
            synchronized (this) {
                CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
                credentialsProvider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY,
                        new UsernamePasswordCredentials(username, password));
                try {
                    HttpClientConfigCallback httpClientConfigCallback = null;
                        httpClientConfigCallback = new HttpClientConfigCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public HttpAsyncClientBuilder customizeHttpClient(
                                    HttpAsyncClientBuilder httpClientBuilder) {
                                return httpClientBuilder
                                        .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(
                                                credentialsProvider);
                            }
                        };

                    restHighLevelClient = new RestHighLevelClient(
                            RestClient.builder(
                                            new HttpHost(elasticSearchHost, port,
                                                    scheme),
                                            new HttpHost(elasticSearchHost2,
                                                    port2, scheme))
                                    .setHttpClientConfigCallback(
                                            httpClientConfigCallback));

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    logger.error("RestHighLevel client create field. Exception: {}",
                            e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }
```

We initiate above client during application startup and close it only when the application is getting shut down.

Then I have written respecitve API using(SerchResponse, multiserachResponse, CountResponse) to fetch the data from ELS.

This code working fine in non PROD environment because of less data. 
However in PROD environment we have huge data, so when we call these API's we were getting below error.

> **2020-05-28T15:24:52.96+0530 [RTR/0] OUT 2020-05-28T15:24:53.72+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR Exception in thread "I/O dispatcher 1"
>   java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Direct buffer memory
>   2020-05-28T15:24:53.72+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR at
>   java.nio.Bits.reserveMemory(Bits.java:694) 2020-05-28T15:24:53.72+0530
>   [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR at
>   java.nio.DirectByteBuffer.(DirectByteBuffer.java:123)
>   2020-05-28T13:37:03.99+0530 [RTR/4] OUT 2020-05-28T13:37:04.25+0530
>   [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2020-05-28 08:07:04.256 ERROR 14 ---
>   [io-8080-exec-10] c.d.d.e.ElasticSearchRepositoryImpl : Exception ::
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Request cannot be executed; I/O
>   reactor status: STOPPED 2020-05-28T13:37:04.25+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0]
>   OUT at org.apache.http.util.Asserts.check(Asserts.java:46)**

Can any one faced such issue, please let me know how to resolve this issue.

Comment: what is the heap size for your elasticsearch process?

Comment: its using by default 1 GB.
-Xms1g
-Xmx1g